# What is the best practice to handle HTTP request in android

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I know about basic ways of request handling in android using `Async Task` or `service` and using `okhttp` library. But I am going to work an a complex production quality app, so I would like to know how experienced people handle http requests in android.

1- Is there any generic way to make http call instead of defining `Async Task and all its method` for every request?

2- Is there any simple way to create a single class/function which I can just call and pass url, parameters and gets its response from any activity or at any point in code

3- I am thinking about using `Realm` so that I can put request data into database directly and then I can get it in activity by using `RealmChangeListener`..... is that a better approach?

Comment: I thought your server would handle http requests.

Answer (score 2):

`Async Task` has been deprecated by Android and shouldn't be used in new code.

- If you're dealing with a REST API or similar, the recommended way is to use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).
- If your requests don't fit into the Retrofit model, one usually uses OkHttp directly. You can wrap your requests and parameters into a method. For Async Handling, either use the callback mechanism of Retrofit or perform your work in a WorkerThread. (Use WorkManager or a Service for long background jobs)
- Haven't used Realm, but heard good of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a work manager in the Jet Pack to do the network call in the background and can receive the data from your network call using its live data observer in the main activity.

Work Manager is quite helpful provide a lot of support in managing the background work and receiving the progress, output data of the task.